# docker-compose up / docker-compose build giving error: Service 'greeter_client' depends on service ' greeter server' which is undefined

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Downloaded the following: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/helloworld

Created  Client.Dockerfile and Server.Dockerfile (and requirements.txt file) built and ran those images, all seemed to work

Tried creating docker-compose.yml file and running docker-compose up but got the error: "Service 'greeter_client' depends on service ' greeter server' which is undefined."

download that wait-for-it.sh script from https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it. used chmod to ensure executable and added depend with that script to my docker-compose.yml (see code below)

Still getting same error: "Service 'greeter_client' depends on service ' greeter server' which is undefined."

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3' 
services: 
  greeter_service: 
    build: 
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Server.Dockerfile 
    ports:  
      - "50051:50051" 
  greeter_client: 
    build: 
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Client.Dockerfile 
    depends_on: 
      - "greeter_server" 
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "greeter_server:50051", "--
", "python3", "greeter_client.py"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've named the service `greeter_service` rather than `greeter_server`.

Change it like this

```
version: '3' 
services: 
  greeter_server: 
    build: 
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Server.Dockerfile 
    ports:  
      - "50051:50051" 
  greeter_client: 
    build: 
      context: . 
      dockerfile: Client.Dockerfile 
    depends_on: 
      - "greeter_server" 
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "greeter_server:50051", "--
", "python3", "greeter_client.py"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how I missed that. I tried to upvote your answer but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation. I really appreciate the accuracy and speed of your answer!